# How to create curlrc file for system-wide usage?

Tags: proxy, suse, sles

I'm trying to setup proxy on my SUSE VM. Following [this](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017441) official guide, I have setup the proxy values in `/etc/sysconfig/proxy` file.

Now in the same article it says to use credentials with proxy, I have to create `.curlrc` file under the user's `$HOME` directory. However I want to use the proxy credentials system-wide for all the users. If so, where can I create this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Everything Curl](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/configfile):

> When curl is invoked, it always (unless -q is used) checks for a default config file and uses it if found.
>
> The default config file is checked for in the following places in this order:
>
> 1. `$CURL_HOME/.curlrc`

- Set `$CURL_HOME` as a system-wide environment variable
- Put the config file in `$CURL_HOME/.curlrc`

Comment: Alright, looks like that did the trick. I exported `CURL_HOME`  in /etc/profile. Then logout & log back-in. Tried curl for all the users. Worked like a charm!